# Do I need to recreate a temp table if a postgres connection refreshes?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2, temp-tables

So I want to upload a temporary table, populate it using a csv file and then run a bunch of other queries with the same connection. Currently I'm uploading a normal table, doing my queries and then dropping it. But I want to make it temporary to avoid confusion and to avoid large amounts of data being left in the db if the code stops for some reason (exception/debugging etc.) before it gets a chance to drop the table. I'm doing all this in python using psycopg2.

Firstly, I've assumed the temporary table will hang around as long as the connection is alive. Is this true? But more importantly, does a psycopg2 db connection ever automatically handle a momentary connection drop out by reestablishing a connection? The queries I'm running are very time consuming so I worry that this could happen. In which case is there some way of knowing when the connection refreshes so I can reupload the temporary table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does a psycopg2 db connection ever automatically handle a momentary connection drop out by reestablishing a connection?

Do you mean does it get impatient, kill a live but "stalled" (e.g. network congestion) connection, and replace it with a new one?  No.  You could probably write code to do that if you wanted (but why would you?) but psycopg2 itself won't do that.

Answer (score 4):

> Firstly, I've assumed the temporary table will hang around as long as
>   the connection is alive. Is this true?

A `TEMPORARY TABLE`  is automatically dropped in the end of your session. So, no garbage is left out when the session ends.

> But more importantly, does the db connection ever drop out and refresh?

Normally a session does not terminate automatically. If you're wondering if temporary tables could generate any conflict in other sessions, you don't have to worry: temporary tables only live inside the current session.

> In which case is there some way of knowing when the connection
>   refreshes so I can reupload the temporary table?

I'm not sure I follow your question here, but one thing is clear: if the session dies, the temporary table dies. If your client is configured to automatically retry to establish connection with the database it won't see the table again. If you want to avoid an error message when trying to create a table that already exists try:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_tmp (...);
```

And to make sure it is empty:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tb_tmp;
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the psycopg2 db connection is truly persistent. If I'm running a bunch of time consuming queries, during which time the db connection momentarily drops out and then reconnects, then my temporary table will disappear and have to be recreated right?

Comment: @Jonathan yes, if the connection drops, the table dies immediately :)

Comment: I've edited the question to try to make it clearer. Basically I was wondering if psycopg2 will automatically reconnect itself to a db if there is some momentary connection drop out. In this case my code would continue to run, but my temporary table will disappear. In which case, how do I tell when this has happened so I can recreate the table? If this never happens then it isn't a worry.

Comment: @Jonathan I see. In this case I'm afraid I cannot help you :) I'm not very familiar with `psycopg2`, so I cannot say if it retries to establish the connection automatically. If it does, the previous temporary table would be gone and you would have to import it all again from the beginning. My advice from the db side would be to: in the beginning of your script check if the table exists either via SQL: `SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.tables 
WHERE  table_schema = 'public'
AND    table_name = 't'` or just trying to create the table again: `CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...;` good luck!

Comment: Yes that is a good idea, perhaps a temporary solution for now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: slightly unrelated: you mention your import takes some time, so consider trying `UNLOGGED TABLES` to speed it up: https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-performance-with-unlogged-tables-in-postgresql/